# How to convert vcard (.vcf files) to an Excel Worksheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vcard

How to convert vcard (.vcf files) to an Excel Worksheet? There are several vcards . How to import all of them to Excel at once?

Comment: Try http://sourceforge.net/projects/vcftoxlsx/.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After downloading the [vcard2xls](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vcf-to-xls) combine all the contacts into 1 file by following the steps below.

**Step 1.** First Copy all your `.vcf` files into one directory.

**Step 2.** Open Windows command prompt and navigate to the folder destination

You can type the `CD **YOUR PATH**` command to reach to your destination

**Step 3.** Enter the following DOS command: `copy *.vcf all.vcf`

The `all.vcf` file will be created

**Step 4.** Open the `vcard2xls` and open this `all.vcf` file.  It will be converted into xls format and then save it.

Finally you will get a `.xls` file with all the contacts in one file.

Comment: alternately, depending on what format you need, you can perform steps 1-3 and then import it into your mail program and then export it out as .csv with the correct headers for your contacts.

Comment: If exporting from OSX Address Book to get a big .vcf file, change its VCF preferences to vCard Format 2.1.

Comment: I would like to add that vcard2xls didn't work for me, it didn't import all contacts (156/714). I used [VCF Import v3.xlsm](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bulkvcftocsv/files/) and it imported all contacts. Other tools didn't helped.